# INotifyPropertyChanged or INotifyCollectionChanged with DataTable?

Tags: wpf, binding, inotifypropertychanged, inotifycollectionchanged

Hi i am having some troube with DataTables. So What i need is to detect whenever i change any cell in the DataGrid of the DataTable that is binded.

How to do it? With `INotifyPropertyChanged` or with `INotifyCollectionChanged`?

Note: I am trying with `INotifyPropertyChanged` but it only detects when i set some value in the DataTable, and never when i change any value of any cell in the DataGrid, i already have tried `OneWay` and `TwoWay` but nothing happens.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The datagrid would be bound to a list of objects. If you want the grid to update when individual object properties change, than *each contained object* must implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

The `INotifyCollectionChanged` is an interface that the collection should implement, and are for notifications of addition and removal events.

See the section "How to implement collections" on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

---

Here's a way to approach your problem:

- Create a new class that exposes the properties currently held in each `DataRow`. On this class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
- Instead of a `DataTable`, use an `ObservableCollection<T>` or your new class.

`ObservableCollection` already implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, so this saves you the effort of implementing it yourself.

Comment: So if i understand right, i will have to turn my DataTable in an IEnumarable, right? And then i will have to implement collections notifications when is inserted or deleted something. But without a real example of using INotifyCollectionChanged is difficult. I already have understand how to work with INotifyPropertyChanged but with collections i haven't find any good example.

Comment: @Miguel - I've added an extra paragraph to answer your concerns.

Comment: dont know why someone downvote me, but i will just add something to this answer. there is no need to create a observablecollection. i use datagrid with itemssource to datatable all over in my project, i can add, modify, delete the content, have validation and filtering and this all without wrapping my datatable. btw i still dont know WHY Miguel wants to know when any cell is changed. there is a HasChanges Property which tell you when there is a change.

Answer (score 0):

if you set the itemssource of your datagrid to a datatable then wpf create a IBindingListView wich is bound to the datagrid.

what you can do now is edit,add and delete items to your datatable via datagrid. if you wanna know when a cell in your datatable is changed you can subscribe to DataTable.ColumnChanged event.

why do you want do know when a cell is changed?

Comment: If you programaticaly modify a cell in your datatable then does your change automatically reflect in the datagrid display?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the title of your question is : Neither. Actually you do not need to bind a DataTable to a DataGrid. You bind a DataView. "The ADO.NET DataView implements the IBindingList interface, which provides change notifications that the binding engine listens for."(Binding Sources Overview)
One answer to your question is :
You modify the datagrid cell with a TextBox (usually). Do this with a new textbox inheriting from TextBox and override the OnGotFocus and OnLostFocus methods of it.