# how to add data to database and show it in datagrid without restarting program?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I can add data to database but there result of it I can only see after restart of my program. How to make it possible to add data and then(immediately. with waiting) see it in another window with datagrid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are binding the DataGrids Items property to your data, or something like that...  Have you implemented [**INotifyPropertyChanged**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) on whatever class your are holding your data in?  This also supposes that you have some way of telling your DataSource to refresh it's data.  If you are issuing SQL commands that insert data, and you have a TableAdapter or something that is storing your local copy, but you don't tell the TableAdapter to refresh from the database, you will never see your changes.

This works best when using MVVM, but you can make it work otherwise.  Essentially, you Add the PropertyChanged event and a handler to your class.  I usually put a call to the handler in my property setter as well as any time I explicitly make changes to the properties value.

This tells the UI that the data has changed in some way, and to refresh the Views representation of it.

## VB Example

```
Public MyClass
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler _
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Protected Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal info As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
End Sub
End Class
```

## C# Example

```
public class DemoCustomer  : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

## ObservableCollection

I am also a huge fan of ObservableCollection.  If you have the means to use it, I suggest it.  It is IEnumerable and has INotifyCollectionChanged implemented on it already.

## Clarification of Databinding

Lets Say you have a class (call it MyData) which you are using to contain your data, in this case a collection of Person objects (ObservableCollection People).  Your XAML might look like this.  This assumes that your MyData class has a default constructor for brevity.

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MyData x:key="mydata"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DataGrid DataContext="{StaticResource mydata}" ItemsSource="{Binding People}"/>
</Window>
```

In this way the DataContext is describi9ng the location of the data, and the ItemsSource is telling what the control should do with it.

[**Code Project article dealing with databinding DataGrid to TableAdapter data.**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGridExamples.aspx)

Comment: I haven't implemented it. I just use an adapter and its method Update.

Comment: Ahh OK.  You might take a look at the link at the bottom.  The CodeProject article describes a number of databinding techniques.  I have never been a big fan of DataTable/DataSet methods of working with data.  Nowadays I almost exclusively use EntityFramework or NHibernate and create CLR classes to work with.

Answer (score 0):

When you add data to the database use `myDataGrid.DataBind()` to re-bind the data.

Comment: there is now such method in WPF datagrid.

Comment: Sorry I must have missed the WPF tag. How are you bindnig your datagrid to the database?

Comment: `mydatagrid.datacontext = x; //x - datatable for examp.`

Comment: CodeWarrior is right... He can probably explain better than me. Here is also a link to another post that explains it better than I could: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798936/inotifypropertychanged-or-inotifycollectionchanged-with-datatable

Comment: DataContext is not really used like that.  On ItemsControls (which DataGrid is a part) there are properties (ItemsSource and Items) that are used to define where the data is coming from.

Comment: And how use ItemsSource and SqlDataAdapter together? I mean for examp. the result of query I put into datatable with Fill and then use `datagrid1.DataContext=table.DefaultView`.

Comment: Actually, it looks like I may be mistaken.  Take a look at the CodeProject link in my post for examples of using a DataGrid with SqlTableAdapter.  Aparently getting the Default View of the TableAdapter for the DataContext is enough to bind.  I have only a little experience dealing with TableAdapters and Datasets and what not.  I abandoned them for ORM solutions like Entity Framework.