# How to add an image at run time in a Listview and DataGrid using linq to sql

Tags: wpf, linq-to-sql, listview

I have a listview and also a DataGrid having records with images. My problem is that when I try to add the record in the listview or in the Datagrid I can only add the string or numbers only but can't add an image. I tried to find it through an openfiledialog box and try to assign to the datagrid cell but i don't know to what to assign the Image at run time if i search for the image. Another problem is that i have been binding the image of the Datagrid but i try to update it and add it at runtime .

And my second problem is updating the image. If any one know about the adding and updating the record in the listview and the also the Datagrid using template so please please for for the sack of God help me i try it but cant fix it . If any one who is expert of wpf please tell me your few minutes can solve my problem please.

My .xmal file is

```
<Window x:Class="UI.ViewClasses"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UI"
    Title="ViewClasses" Height="300" Width="456" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Window.Resources >
        <local:ImageConverter x:Key="ImageDataConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <my:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="DataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="12,51,80,35" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="Cell" CanUserReorderColumns="True" CanUserResizeColumns="True" 
          CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="True"  IsReadOnly="False" LoadingRow="DataGrid_LoadingRow"  AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue"

         Loaded="DataGrid_Loaded">
            <my:DataGrid.Columns>

                <my:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="     Frist Name">
                    <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" 
                                         Margin="-6,0,-6,0"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </my:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <my:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="   Last Name">
                    <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=LastName}" 
                                         Margin="-6,0,-6,0"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </my:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <my:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="   Gender">
                    <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Gender}" 
                                         Margin="-6,0,-6,0"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </my:DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <my:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="   GPA">
                    <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                           <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=GPA}" 
                                         Margin="-6,0,-6,0"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </my:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <my:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="   Image">
                    <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Height="50" Name="image1" Source="{Binding Path=MyImage, Converter={StaticResource ImageDataConverter}}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </my:DataGridTemplateColumn>


            </my:DataGrid.Columns>
        </my:DataGrid>
        <Button Height="30" Margin="12,10,0,0" Name="btnAdd" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="75" Click="btnAdd_Click">Add</Button>
        <Button Height="30" Margin="166,10,0,0" Name="btnSave" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btnSave_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="75">Save</Button>
        <Button Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="92,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Name="btnDelete" Click="btnDelete_Click">Delete</Button>
        <Button Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,112,0" Name="Browses" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="83" Click="Browses_Click">Brows</Button>
        <TextBox Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,0,0" Name="txtBrowseFile" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110" />
    </Grid>
</Window>

And my .xaml.cs file is 

namespace UI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ViewClasses.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ViewClasses : Window
    {
        public ViewClasses()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        } private DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();

        private BindingListCollectionView CustomerView;

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
         {
             DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
             var custsInCA = from c in db.Students                             
                             select c;

             this.DataContext = custsInCA;
             this.CustomerView = ((BindingListCollectionView)(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.DataContext)));

        }

        private void DataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRowEventArgs e)
        { 


        }

        private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.db.SubmitChanges();
                MessageBox.Show("Saved");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Student st = ((Student)(this.CustomerView.AddNew()));

            st.LastName = "<new>";
            this.CustomerView.CommitNew();
            this.DataGrid.ScrollIntoView(st);
        }

        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((this.CustomerView.CurrentPosition > -1))
            {
                this.CustomerView.RemoveAt(this.CustomerView.CurrentPosition);
            }

        }

        private void Browses_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Image image1 = new Image();
            Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid df = new Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid(); 
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog fileChooser = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            fileChooser.Filter = " Image files|*.jpg;*.gif;*.bmp;*.png;;*.jpeg";
            Nullable<bool> result = fileChooser.ShowDialog();
            if (result == true)

                try
                {

                    txtBrowseFile.Text = fileChooser.FileName;

                }
                catch { return; }
            if (txtBrowseFile.Text.Trim().Length != 0)
            {
                BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
                src.BeginInit();
                src.UriSource = new Uri(txtBrowseFile.Text.Trim(), UriKind.Relative);
                src.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                src.EndInit();

                image1.Source = src;
            }         
        }       
    }

    public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,

        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            System.Data.Linq.Binary binaryData = value as System.Data.Linq.Binary;
            //System.Data.Linq.Binary binaryData = value;// here there is the first error .How convert BinaryData to Object??
            if (binaryData == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            byte[] buffer = binaryData.ToArray();
            if (buffer.Length == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }

            BitmapImage res = new BitmapImage();
            res.BeginInit();
            res.StreamSource = new System.IO.MemoryStream(buffer);
            res.EndInit();
            return res;
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

}
```

My problem is that I want to add the record at runtime I can add the other record but cant image and also can't update the image at run time in the datagrid. If there is any expert in the wpf then please replay my and replay me if possible in full detail that I can understand I have electric load shading problem in my country so I can't quick respond to you so please if possible respond me for the sack of God I just wishing the noble persons those how helping me .

Comment: I noticed that you have UriKind.Relative specified in the URISource property.  If you are returning a path from a file dialog, the URI is not going to be relative, but absolute.  It will denote Drive and Directory structure from root to the file.

Comment: It is nice but what is the problem of my solution Dear CodeWarrior

Comment: If it is treating the path as relative instead of absolute, it is going to resolve the wrong path.  Lets assume your path is "C:\MyPics\Pic1.png".  It thinks it is a relative path, so it resolves it as relative to the folder from which the program is running (I think) and thus it comes out as "C:\Program Files(x86)\MyProgram\C\MyPics\Pic1.png"  That picture is not there, so it has nothing to render.  So far as I can tell what you are doing is fine, I have done it myself before in a similar fashion.

Comment: Thanks to replay but i can't understand my code that i try to retrieve Image from sql serber in at sql server my image is in varbinary(max) type. So if i try to show my image then i have to converte it from varbinary to byte and i think i need to to use i INotifyPropertyChanged  but i try to do this i can do it becasue i am new in wpf know my second question in the stackoverflow which will solve my that question i think so. So If you you have some knowledge about the INotifyPropertyChanged then write for my . I will be very thank full to you sir

Comment: In addition to my post below, I will tell you that I have always been told it is better to host images on the file system and a reference to them in the database.  Especially if you have lots and lots of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have previously posted an answer with some info about [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419015/how-to-add-data-to-database-and-show-it-in-datagrid-without-restarting-program/8419477#8419477).

[how to add data to database and show it in datagrid without restarting program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419015/how-to-add-data-to-database-and-show-it-in-datagrid-without-restarting-program/8419477#8419477)

Let me know if that is satisfacctory to your purpose of if you require additional help.

## EDIT

One thing I would do is change the way you are working with your items.

```
    DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    var custsInCA = from c in db.Students                             
         select c;

    this.DataContext = custsInCA;
    this.CustomerView = ((BindingListCollectionView)(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.DataContext)));
```

I generally use something more like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<Student> Students = null;
public CollectionViewSource cvs = new CollectionViewSource;
public ViewClasses()
{
    cvs.Source = Students;
    InitializeComponent();
}
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Open Context
    DataClasses1DataContext db new DataClasses1DataContext();
    //Populate ObservableCollection with objects
    Students = 
        new ObservableCollection<Student>((from c in db.Students select c).ToList());
    //Raise PropertyChangedNotification
    OnPropertyChanged("Students");
}
```

And in XAML:

```
<my:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding cvs}" Name="DataGrid">
```

In this way, your DataGrids ItemsSource is bound directly to the CollectionViewSource, the CollectionViewSource is fed by the Students collection, and the change notification of change is sent up when the Students collection has been updated.

The above code is just test code, there may be some spelling or punctuation mistakes.  I am unfortunatly on the bus right now and not at my desk.

Also, are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: @Yaqoob Abbasi  You may find that further questions that you ask may not get any answers.  You have not upvoted or marked an answer yet.  If any of the above is helpful to you, please let me know.  If it is not, let me know why and I can continue trying to help.

Comment: Respectable CodeWarrior When i try to do this in my separate project means i try to recreat me project once again then i have error in my code which is NOtImpelmenttationException on the line of the One property change please tell me who to solve this problem i will be very thanks full to you very very

Comment: And when i try to use my student class me creating new class naming Student lke this  public class Student : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        } Then error is ocure which is Missing partial modifier of type wpfApplication3

Comment: Know i understand that why my question account is block for stack overflow team i am very thankful to all of you but actually i don't know that who to use this website i just want to learn the wpf but my account is sealed i don't know why but know i understand that what is my mistake so i say sorry to all those respondent who responding me and also say sorry to the stack overflow team as will  Thanks to all of you