# SignalR vs Timers in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, signalr

I have used timers to update the content of a data grid in WPF. But some data are not displayed, and when I refresh the page, they are displayed. So I feel like this is not the best approach.

Can I use SignalR instead of timers to Update the content of a WPF data grid? If yes, are there any advantages of using SignalR here?

Comment: Please provide the code you've tried so far. Maybe, your code is just missing something. And try to be more specific, because you're actually asking 2 questions at the same time.

Comment: I don't think you'll need SignalR to fix this. Are you sure you're raising INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyCollectionChanged and raising PropertyChanged and CollectionChanged correctly? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798936/inotifypropertychanged-or-inotifycollectionchanged-with-datatable).